# How can I set MKAnnotationView's level of MKMapView?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to set `MKUserLocation` view on the top of the map. Now it is blocked by other `MKUserLocation` view.

What can I do to move it to the top?

Comment: try `bringSubViewToFront:`

Comment: There is no Z ordering provided by Apple's MapKit. So try inserting annotations in the order you want to show them. The annotation added last would be visible at the top.